# Has Freemarker something similar to toolbox.xml-file of Velocity?

Tags: struts, javabeans, velocity, freemarker, toolbox

I have a Struts 1 application which works with Velocity as a template language. I shall replace Velocity with Freemarker, and am looking for something similar to 'toolbox.xml'-File from VelocityViewServlet. (there you can map names to Java Classes and, using these names it is possible to access methods and variables of various Java class in the Velocity template).
Does someone know, what is possible with Freemarker instead? So far I have found only information about the form beans...would be glad if someone can help....

Comment: You don't need it with FreeMarker.

Comment: thanks for your reply. and how is it possible to create new instances of Java classes and put it into the data model, so that Freemarker templates have access to these instances?

Comment: in Velocity, as I wrote, you just need the toolbox.xml file and everything else happens internally..

Comment: Just put them in the request. If you want them there all the time, consider something like a filter that adds them, or just keep them in the application context.

Comment: could you give me maybe a little example? would be very helpful...

Comment: An example of how to put an object into the application context?

Comment: well, yes...sorry if it's a stupid question, but I've only recently started with struts and don't know how it is working internally....

Comment: Putting things into application context from a filter has nothing to do with Struts, though.

Comment: I also don't know much about servlets, though...

Comment: someone helped me to create a filter class looking like this:

Comment: You might want to get some basics down before replacing components wholesale--how will you debug errors if you don't understand the environment in which you're operating?

Comment: public class Filter implements ServletContextListener
{
 private static ServletContext context = null;


// ########################################################################################
 public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)
  {
  context = event.getServletContext();

  SomeClass someClass = new someClass();
  context.setAttribute("someClass", someClass );
  

  // init();

 }

Comment: well, my main task is only dealing with freemarker, and I don't have the time to get really into struts and servlets....thw whole project already works well with velocity and I managed to integrate freemarker, just don't know how to put data into the data model..

Comment: Did you read [this](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_misc_servlet.html)?

Comment: the filter-class above I then integrated into 'web.xml' using <listener>
      <listener-class>Filter</listener-class>
   </listener>    did you mean it like that? yet I still can't access "someClass"...and of course you're right, I'd like it better to understand it all but probably if this problem is solved I have everything what I need to replace velocity with freemarker...

Comment: yes I read this...but I didn't see how it can help me in this case

Answer (score 1):

For the utility functions and macros that are View-related (not Model-related), the standard practice is to implement them in FreeMarker and put them into one or more templates and #import (or #include) them. It's also possible to pull in `TemplateDirectiveModel`-s and `TemplateMethodModelEx`-es (these are similar to macros and function, but they are implemented in Java) into the template that you will #import/#inlcude as `<#assign foo = 'com.example.Foo'?new()>`.

As of calling plain static Java methods, you may use the `ObjectWrapper`'s `getStaticModels()` (assuming it's a `BeansWrapper` subclass) and then get the required methods as `TemplateMethodModelEx`-es with `staticModels.get("com.example.MyStatics")`. Now that you have them, you can put them into the data-model (Velocity context) in the Controller, or pick methods from them in an #import-ed template, etc. Of course, you can also put POJO objects into the data-model so you can call their non-static methods.

The third method, which is not much different from putting things into the data-model is using "shared variables", which are variables (possibly including `TemplateMethodModelEx`-es and `TemplateDirectiveModel`-s) defined on the `Configuration` level.

Comment: thank you for answering... I'll take a closer look at it tomorrow:)

Comment: @ddekany: could you give me a code example concerning the 2nd and 3rd method? would be very helpful.